# how to addition doubles in flutter

Tags: dart

i have a list of doubles, that i want to show the result of addition all of those,
i did this before but i couldn't show those with this ,
indeed, i got the same element in each time
what is the best way to do that,
i'm really confused

```
void main() {
  List<double> list= [1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.8,52.9];
  double total = 0.0;
  for (var item in list) {
  
    var all= item+ total;
    print(all);
  }
}
```

please tell me what i did wrong

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Adding to João's answer:

The best looking answer could be something like:

```
var result = list.reduce((a,b) => a+b));
```

The reduce method of a list have the same effect on a list.

Comment: Technically this is the ideal answer, but taking into account that the user seems to not be experienced at writing code, I would say that this answer might not really help him understand his mistake.

Answer (score 0):

You have an `all` variable being declared inside the `for` loop. It gets re-declared every time the loop runs. If you just want the total value, you just add it on every loop and print it out:

```
void main() {
  List<double> list= [1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.8,52.9];
  double total = 0.0;
  for (var item in list) {
    total = item + total;
    print(total);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `fold` method as well:

```
void main() {
  final list = [1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,0.8,52.9];
  final result = list.fold(0, (a, b) => a + b);
  print(result);
}
```